# Stripe Payment: Externally managed subscription

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription, recurring-billing

I want to create a checkout with subscription plan. The visitor will see a page with "you're going to pay X for one month".

Usually someone would create one or many subscriptions in Stripe.

For legacy reasons, this does not work for me, thus i want to trigger the recurring payments from my own managed backend.

Is it possible to ask the visitor (payer) for a recurring payment, which then will be initiated from my own system?

Comment: Yes it's possible, you get a token `tok_XXX` and then you save it on a customer and do what you want with it

Comment: So you wanna do the recurring part from your own? You mean you will trigger/manage the recurring charge/payment whenever you want for a customer?